# How to save credit card details in Paypal vault via Android and how to retrieve them to use them in future

Tags: android, paypal, credit-card

I need to integrate Paypal Payment in my application. I have integrated the same successfully by referring to the below links:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-paypal-in-android

Now, if I use a credit card for payment, I can process the payment using Paypal.

**Concerned Issue**

Now if I need to use the credit card again to perform some other payment. I need that the card should be saved in the vault of the paypal server and should be shown in my application wallet. and only required information such as CVV No. or Pin etc. should be entered by the user and the card can perform its operation.
I am using the below link. But it doesn't clear my thoughts how to use it.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/

Can anyone provide any help or guidance for this issue?

Comment: Hi,I am facing the same issue. Did you find anything? Meanwhile, I tried their java sdk https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call , but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

we can call vault pay pal api using retrofit library and following the steps mentioned in below two links of pay pal.First we have to call the first restful pay pal api to get access token.Once we get this access token we can call the vault api of pay pal to store credit card.Below are links for pay pal restful api:

1) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

2) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/vault/

I was able to store credit card details using retrofit library and following proper steps to pass the parameters and using proper headers in retrofit.